# How to read this schematic correctly

Tags: wiring, schematic

This schematic will be used to wire a potentiometer and momentary on switch to a welder. The schematic states that there is a cable shield grounded to the connector. Am I correct to assume that this simply means that the cable I use should be shielded and, if so, how will it connect to the 6-pin connector? Also, what is the meaning of the capacitance between the wires? Is it only telling me that there is capacitance between the wires or am I expected to wire something there?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that the ground is primarily for safety purposes, i.e., preventing electric shock, since there is no electrical connection to the parts, only to the chassis. Another purpose might be to prevent the *large* transients and radiated RF from welding from affecting the control circuit (as wouldthe two capacitors across the pot).

Likely, the schematic is for an OEM part that *already* contains the two caps, as well as the switch and pot, since no value is given for capacitance, unless indicated on a separate BOM (bill of materials).

Answer (score 0):

The diagram does state that there is a cable shield. The shield is connected to the metal case of the connector whether it is the 6-pin or 12-pin.

[image]

It is not clear from the diagram what information is implied by the capacitor symbols.

Answer (score 0):

The cable shield connects to each connector body, possibly with a clamp around the cable as part of a strain relief.  It does not connect to any of the connector pins at either end.  The pin spacing is not right for high voltage signals, so my guess is that the cable shield is only that, a noise shield.